# Libtorrent, Python, how set download speed

Tags: python, libtorrent

Is there any way to change the speed of dowload in [libtorrent library](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html) form Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "set" the download speed, however you can limit it. This can be done by using
torrent_handle::set_download_limit(int limit)

in python:

```
h = ses.add_torrent(info, "tmp")
h.set_download_limit(2048)
```

will limit your download speed to 2kB/s